# How can I set the input signal to LTspice with equal intervals?

Tags: ltspice, sampling

In transient analysis I define a voltage input such as a square wave input and obtain an output voltage. Here I set the input signal:

[image]

Export time series:

[image]

But when I export the input and export time series signals from LTspice as a text, the time points do not have equal intervals. From the text file time plotted:

[image]

Is it possible to set it so we have an input and output with equal time intervals? Such as a sampled input and output with a constant sampling rate fs.

Comment: A [very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/340475/6334) was asked just a couple days ago.

Comment: I set the max timestep to 0.00008 still same number of samples and same issue nothing change. I think that question is lacking example imao I didnt get the solution which parameter is what ect.

Comment: Can you put your spice file (the netlist file) on pastebin or somewhere?

Comment: Yes here is the asc file: http://wikisend.com/download/511398/fltrtest22.asc

Comment: Why do you want equal intervals?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Because I will use a system identification tool and the tool needs the sampling time(1/fs) to process the data. Related to my previous question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340818/obtaining-bode-plots-by-using-laplace-transform-and-time-domain-data-from-spice I will compare the LTspice's Bode plots and the system identification's transfer function. I plan to use it in real scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting LTspice waveforms to txt or csv](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42254/exporting-ltspice-waveforms-to-txt-or-csv)

Comment: The problem is not with the input signal, it is with the stimulation time. You can either force the timestep in the .tran command OR use a .meas statment and measure the time that way OR just use the interp function after you load the data into matlab

Answer (score 1):

To 'sample' nodes in LTspice you can use the `.WAVE` command to create a WAV audio file. The maximum resolution is 32 bits and maximum sampling frequency is 4096MHz.

The plot below was produced from your LTspice schematic. It was created in LTspice with `.wave fltrtest22.wav 16 50 V(in) V(out)` which specifies 16 bits and 50sps, then converted to csv text data using [Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (command line: '`sox fltrtest22.wav -t dat fltrtest22.csv`'), loaded into Openoffice Calc as merged space-delimited text, and finally plotted on an x-y scatter chart.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget that the downside of this is the limit between +/-1V.

Comment: Yes, the 'audio' waveforms saturate at +-1V. Just have to set the input to a level that ensures the output doesn't saturate.